# Loading a web page in unity

Tags: unity, web

Hello I need to open a page in unity and save some of it's contents but I have absolutely no idea how I should do it.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this plugin. A few on the asset store are a little pricey when it comes to embedded browsers (as I'm assuming that's what you want to display the web page) but this one is free and open-source. 
https://bitbucket.org/vitaly_chashin/simpleunitybrowser

It also appears to have settings to save web page data. If you don't mind me asking, what data do you need to save? If it's user data, there are more elegant ways of solving this particular problem, i.e. https://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-save-and-load-your-players-progress-in-unity--cms-20934

If not, then this seems like your best bet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
What I need is to save a few thousand words and load them later so I will look at that.